# Is possible to render in Cycles with modifiers on the scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, modifiers

I'm a little bit newbie in Blender, I'm come from Maya and I'm still improving my skills on it hehe

I was making a tutorial about make tank tracks, but I have a problem. I made all the animation for the tank tracks, and it works fine, the problem is that I need to conserve the modifiers (Curve modifier and array) in order to keep the animation working, but I cannot render with modifiers without apply...

So, how can I render the model in cycles and don't loose this animation rigging? The tracks are linked to an empty cube, and rigged by using drivers.

Thanks for your help and consideration :)

Kind regards!

Comment: You should never have to remove or apply modifiers to render, unless you want to. Except for a few circumstances and specific uses, 3D applications are generally design to keep modifiers around as a non destructive workflow, for as long as possible.

What problems are you experiencing while rendering? What can't you render or what happens when you do? Post some screenshots or a Blend file. Some times render results differ from viewport preview because some modifiers have distinct settings for viewport and rendering, leading some times to unexpected results.

Comment: You probably accidentally disabled rendering with modifiers somewhere in the stack.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [the manual here](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface), each modifier has a few buttons that enable/disable it at certain times. The small camera button is used to for displaying the modified result when rendering, if this is off it will not be visible when rendering.

Answer (score 3):

The modifiers do not need to be applied in order to render.

If the effect of the modifier is not showing at render time it's probably because it has been disabled for rendering (the camera icon).

[image]

Those icons determine the if the modifier renders or not (camera icon), if it's effects are visible on the 3Dvieport (eye icon), if it is displayed in Edit mode (cube with orange dots). Additionally in some instances there is a fourth option to edit the resulting geometry in edit mode (the triangle icon)

Applying the modifiers makes the transformations permanent, whereas the beauty of working with modifiers is being able to use a non-destructive workflow where the elements remain editable. You should only need to apply the modifiers in rare occasions, mosty when exporting to different formats that do not support modifiers from blender.